# Rendering MP4 Video with Expression Encoder for IE10

Tags: html, internet-explorer, html5-video, internet-explorer-10

I am rendering video as MP4 (H.264) using Expression Encoder. I am choosing the H.264 Screen Encoding VBR profile. It produces an .mp4 file that I can play on my computer (I'm on Windows 8 RTM) using Media Player and when I put it on my site I can see the video play in Google Chrome, but it won't play in IE10. Any reason why not or how to go about troubleshooting this?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a lovely IE10 bug as described here...

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/iewebdevelopment/thread/d62f0aa3-76d1-4d3a-b0a6-bb3731402f83

I think the short of it - if you have specified the codec parameter as you should do eg:

IE10 throws a wobbly. If you strip the codec declaration out it should work. Not sure what the repercussions of this might be though